# When is "in finding" and "of finding" grammatical?

Tags: grammar, idiomatic-language

I heard that only the first is correct of the three:

> I am on the way to find you.
>
> I am on the way in finding you.
>
> I am on the way of finding you.

Then why is the following from Social Networks and Migration: Far West Nepalese Labour Migrants in Delhi by Susan Thieme, correct?

> However, such bonding social capital might be only useful in a limited
>   **way in finding** a higher-skilled and better-paid job.

Or the following from The Way of Jesus: Living a Spiritual and Ethical Life by Jay Parini?

> It's a **way of finding** God within ourselves, the “paradise within" that
>   Milton wrote about in Paradise Lost.

Comment: They are three different sense of *way*... full answer to follow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

These three use ***way*** in different senses, including idiom or set phrase constructions. In all cases, it descends from the basis of *way* meaning path or route, and you will find 'way' used as part of street names on this same basis. But there's a lot of significant (if subtle) difference in different ways of using it.

So, let's look at each.

> I'm **on the way** to find you

To be "on the way" or "on one's way" to something is to be part-way there. It is also used metaphorically for non-physical journeys, as in The Proclaimers *I'm On My Way*:

> *I'm **on my way** from misery to happiness today*

Thus one might be on one's way *from* or *to* somewhere or something, including a non-finite verb clause. You could also be on your way *through* or *past* things, *into* or *out of* things, or even use the zero preposition, as in "on my way home". In that sense, however, one cannot be on the way *in* or *of*, certainly not as a preposition leading into a non-finite verb clause.

> only useful **in a limited way** in finding a higher-skilled and better-paid job

This is actually an example of ***in a way***, a set prepositional phrase meaning *in a sense* or *to some extent*. This phrase generally functions to limit the degree of other expressions, or to limit approval or agreement in conversation.

> "So, you're saying I'm to stupid to take this course?"
>
> "**In a way**, yes."

In that example, a person is trying to soften what they are saying; they are recognising that the first speaker is, to some extent, correct in their summary, but that it should not be put so simply. They would then try to explain it in more detail.

In your example, it is itself modified by *limited*, thus reducing the degree further. The important thing about the word after the phrase, however, is that the phrase is inserted with little impact on the grammar of the words around it. It could be elided and we would expect the sentence to remain grammatical: "only useful ... in finding a higher-skilled or better-paid job". The ellipsis removes meaning, but shows us the grammatical structure - *in* follows *useful*. We might rephrase it as

"only slightly useful in finding a higher-skilled or better-paid job"

And that makes clear why *in* is used as it is; it is nothing to do with *way* preceding it.

> It's a **way** of finding God within ourselves

This is the only case of the three where the meaning of *way* is not determined by being part of a set phrase. Here it follows the basic meaning of *route* or *path* by analogy to become essentially synonymous with *method*. It is acting purely as a noun, with a prepositional phrase giving it additional meaning.

We can thus see that what prepositions might follow the word **way** depend entirely on which sense of the word is being invoked.

Answer (score 3):

These different contexts for "way" are a little tricky to parse out.

"I am on the way to find you." uses the idiom "on the way" + infinitive [to-verb], meaning "in the process of [doing s/t]." Naturally, you have "the way *to*" in the sentence.

"... might be only useful in a limited way in finding a ... job," uses a different expression, "useful in" + gerund [verb-ing]. There is a parenthetical, side-remark inserted in between "useful" and "in". So it looks at first like the "way" of the side-remark is related to the "in" from the other expression, but this is only an accident.

Your last example, "It's a way of finding ..." uses "way" as a simple noun in the sense of "method". "Of finding" in this case just modifies the noun, "way."

So the prepositions are different, but that is because of different requirements for different *ways* of using "way".